# Why am I getting "Menu Function object not initialized" error when using a menu item for a report in ax 2012 X++?

Tags: report, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

We are converting from AX2009 to AX2012 R2 (15 Jan 2013 edition). We are converting the old reports to the "deprecated" reports functionality in AX2012 R2 to save time in re-developing all our own reports. The process has been going fine but I am getting this error: "Menu Function object not initialized" on some reports. If I run those reports directly, they work fine. Other reports work fine with menu items.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to overcome this will be greatly appreciated. I can see no real difference between the structure, methods used, properties etc. between the reports that do work and the ones that doesn't.

Please keep in mind that none of these reports are SSRS. Where there are data structure changes I overcome these by writing methods in the reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that the menu items points to a valid report.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did check the menu items over and over again and even deleted it and recreated it from scratch. The reports are valid as they run when invoked directly. Also all the propertiess on the menu items are correct. The re object is also of type "Report" and not "SSRS Report" which is correct. There are no such report names existing under SSRS Reports either.

Comment: MenuFunction object not initialized.

Stack trace

(C)\Classes\RunbaseReportStd\reportIsRunOnServer - line 9
(C)\Classes\RunbaseReportStd\hideBatchTab - line 6
(C)\Classes\RunbaseReportStd\dialogMake - line 14
(C)\Classes\RunBase\promptPrim - line 23
(C)\Classes\RunBase\prompt - line 12
(C)\Classes\RunBaseBatch\prompt - line 30
(C)\Classes\RunBaseReport\prompt - line 40
(C)\Classes\SysReportRun\run - line 13

Comment: Consider installing the CU1 to AX 2012 R2. It may be a corrected error. Consider debugging the error.

Comment: Somehow the problem went away without anything specific that we've done. (Mystery)